# Extract password during python script execution

Tags: python, unix, passwords

```
Password = subprocess.call(["openssl",
    "enc",
    "-d", "-aes-256-cbc",
    "-a",
    "-in", "/home/xxx/xxx/pvcsadminPWwin.enc",
    "-pass", "pass:password"])
```

During the execution of this Python script, I want the password to be extracted.

And when the script executes the password gets printed by default on the screen.

But when I give

```
print Password
```

it prints `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lutz for giving me a track to proceed, and after trying a lot many things, i observed the below things.

`Password = subprocess.call(["openssl",
    "enc",
    "-d", "-aes-256-cbc",
    "-a",
    "-in", "/home/xxx/xxx/pvcsadminPWwin.enc",
    "-pass", "pass:password"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = Password.communicate()
    print stdout[:-1]`

stdout is a string having endline character in the end. so i picked the whole string except the last character.
and then it returns the correct password.

Answer (score 1):

[`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) returns the return code of the called command.

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

Use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Comment: I am using python 2.6.6 and used subprocess.Popen()
But it gives output like:         
`<subprocess.Popen object at 0x2b0c9e0c25d0>`